# Are Certain Religious Terms Capitalized?

Tags: editing, non-fiction, book

Is the term, "the great falling away" directly from the Bible, capitalized when used in a sentence to emphasize its importance? Also, the term "last days" is in question.

Comment: Hi Suzette - welcome to the community.
I'm not sure whether this question is on topic, but I should point out that 'the great falling away' as a phrase does not appear in the Bible (at least not in the King James Version) - it is usually referred to with ref to Ephesians. Initial capitalisation then becomes a matter of personal stylistic choice. Again, I would expect 'last day' - and here a good dictionary would be of more help than this site - see https://www.lexico.com/definition/last_day - consider rephrasing in line with guidelines - you may get a better answer. Hope this helps. Leon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Some terms](https://www.theatlantic.com/national/archive/2014/05/style-guide-for-religion/371813/) are always capitalized, like Holy Ghost.

Specific and important religious **events** are capitalized in [many](https://calvin.edu/offices-services/communications-marketing/tools-resources/editorial-style-guide/religious-terms.html) style [guides](https://styleguide.efca.org/evangelical-terminology/) (the Creation, the Crucifixion, the [Flood](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flood), the Resurrection, the Second Coming, etc.), but [not all](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0310487714).

The "great falling away" (=apostasy/rebellion - [2 Thessalonians 2:3](https://biblia.com/bible/esv/2-thessalonians/2/3)) is less talked about than the Flood or the Second Coming, but if *you* interpret it as a *single* and *major* event, you could argue for its capitalization. Otherwise, I would caution against it (but context matters).